# etale localization reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm looking for a reference for the following statement:

Let $P$ be a property of morphisms of schemes local on the target in the etale topology. Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes which is locally of finite presentation, and such that for all points $y\in Y$, the restriction of $f$ to the strict henselian local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}^{sh}$ has property $P$. Then $f$ has property $P$.

(Is the LoFP condition necessary?)

This seems to follow from various results in the stacks project, but I can't find it explicitly stated anywhere except for the specific case where P = "flat" (tag 05VL).

I need this result for an appendix in my thesis. Currently I've stitched a proof together using various results of the stacks project, but it seems more elegant to cite a reference that proves this explicitly if possible.

Comment: You could contribute it to the stacks project.

Comment: There exist people who do not like the stacks project as a reference because it has not been refereed. I am not suggesting that I am one of those people, but refereeing is part of the academic process -- although probably far more so in other sciences. The argument is that "I am written by a smart guy" should not be enough -- look at the ABC fiasco for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not true without further hypotheses, but it is true with one additional hypothesis.  First, here is a counterexample.  Let $P$ be the property that the morphism $f$ is quasi-compact.  This property is local for the étale topology, and even for the fpqc topology, cf. http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KQ for instance.

Let $Y$ be $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}$, and let $X$ be the disjoint union over all primes $p$ of $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  There is a unique morphism $f:X\to Y$.  This morphism is not quasi-compact since $X$ is not quasi-compact.  The morphism $f$ is locally of finite presentation since every point of $X$ has an open neighborhood that is isomorphic to $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$.

On the other hand, for every closed point $y=\langle p\rangle$ of $Y$ the base change of $f$ over the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} = \mathbb{Z}_{\langle p \rangle}$ is the quasi-compact, even affine, morphism corresponding to the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{\langle p \rangle} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\langle p \rangle}/p\mathbb{Z}_{\langle p \rangle}$.  Thus the base change of $f$ to every strict Henselization is also quasi-compact.

The simplest additional hypothesis guaranteeing your result is "compatible with filtered limits of schemes / filtered colimits of rings": for every affine scheme $Y=\text{Spec}\ A$ that is a filtered colimit $A = \varinjlim A_\lambda$ of rings $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in I}$, for every compatible family of morphisms $$f_\lambda:X_\lambda \to \text{Spec}\ A_\lambda, \ \ \phi_{\mu,\lambda}:X_\mu \xrightarrow{\cong} X_{\lambda}\otimes_{A_\lambda} A_\mu,$$ with filtered limit $f:X\to \text{Spec}\ A$, then $f$ has property $P$ if and only if there exists some $\lambda$ in $I$ such that for all $\mu>\lambda$, $f_\mu$ has property $P$.  There are many examples of such properties in EGA $\textrm{IV}_3$, Section 8.10, pp. 36-41. (Please note, in EGA, there is a standing hypothesis that every $f_\lambda$ is finitely presented, i.e., locally finitely presented and quasi-compact. Also I have stated "compatible with limits" slightly incorrectly because I am only considering the case that $Y$ is affine.  The correct formulation is in EGA.  If your property is étale local on the base, then you can always reduce to the affine case.)

Since the strict henselization $A$ of a Noetherian ring $B$ at a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is a filtered colimit of finitely presented, étale $B$-algebras, if your property is compatible with limits and is also étale local, then it holds on $\text{Spec} B$ if and only if it holds after base change to each strict Henselization $\text{Spec}\ B_{\mathfrak{p}}^{sh}$.

Comment: The definition of "finitely presented" requires "quasi-separated" too (as J.S. knows).  Also, it is worth noting that EGA has a many more instances of such properties P later on, such as flatness (11.2.6), smooth, etale, unramified (IV$_4$, 17.7.8), and differential smoothness (17.12.6); overall EGA remains the best source on such limit results. But for the original question with P = "flat" none of this discussion (nor LFP) is needed, since the OP's hypotheses (with **all** $y\in Y$) makes it an elementary exercise with flatness because each $O_y \rightarrow O_y^{\rm{sh}}$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: The stacks project so far has P = "affine", "finite", "unramified", "closed immersion", "separated", "flat", "finite locally free", "smooth", "etale", "isomorphism", "monomorphism", "surjective", "syntomic", "proper", "quasi-finite", and "at-worst-nodal of relative dimension 1". Most can be found in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/081C and it is usually straighforward to add new ones.

Comment: @CountDracula: Is the proof for flatness in the Stacks Project simpler than (or much different from) the one in EGA?  (There are very many back-references to chase down in the SP version, so I can't tell at a glance how it compares with Raynaud's proof in EGA.)

Comment: @nfdc23 I think it is about the same complexity and essentially the same. I think in both the key ingredient is openness of flatness for fp ring map, but I read the proof in EGA a really long time ago so I am not completely sure. Still the graph http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JO/graph/force of logical implication does not look too big!

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your answer! Do you know if any quasi-separated and quasi-compact assumptions (as for example in EGA packaged with finite presentation, or in the stacks project tag 081D) is necessary if we work only over affine $Y$ (since as you say we can reduce to this case)? It seems to me that at least if the property is in addition Zariski local on the source, then we shouldn't need any qcqs assumptions right? (My understanding is that qcqs is only required when extending results over affines that require finite presentation to results over general schemes)

Comment: @wyc: No, you definitely need a finite presentation assumption to spread-out from local rings to ambient affine base schemes, for example; it is not just a device to bootstrap beyond the affine case.  Jason Starr gives you an example of failure of spreading-out from stalks on $Y$ with $Y$ affine.

Comment: @nfdc23 I mean, suppose P is a property of morphisms Zariski local on the source and etale local on the target, and suppose f is only *locally of finite presentation*. Would showing that has P after base changing to strict local rings suffice to show that f has P? (Are you saying that you still need qcqs assumptions on f in this case? Doesn't being local on the source reduce to considering morphisms between affine schemes, which is always qcqs?)